# Ubuntu/pipewire/bluez: headset not working with HSP/HFP profile

Tags: bluez, pipewire

After connecting my bluetooth headset I am able to listen to audio with the A2DP sink profiles. However, when I want to use my mic and switch to HSP/HFP for this, I have no input nor output audio. It's not a problem of my headset because I also tried a second one which has the same problem.

I am on TuxedoOS 2 (which is essentialy ubuntu "22.04.4") and using pipewire/bluez.

Switching the profile and starting audio results in the following output from

```
journalctl -f --user
```

LOG

```
mrt 19 18:43:23 tuxedoos pipewire-pulse[8344]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x60dd7d33e740 [PulseAudio Volume Control]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:4294967295 error:25 (Input/output error)
mrt 19 18:43:23 tuxedoos pipewire-pulse[8344]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x60dd7d267a80 [Plasma PA]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:4294967295 error:25 (Input/output error)
mrt 19 18:43:23 tuxedoos wireplumber[8343]: (bluez_input.00_04_32_8E_48_A2.0-107) running -> error (Received error event)
mrt 19 18:43:23 tuxedoos wireplumber[8343]: (bluez_output.00_04_32_8E_48_A2.1-100) suspended -> error (Received error event)
mrt 19 18:43:23 tuxedoos wireplumber[8343]: Failure in Bluetooth audio transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_04_32_8E_48_A2/fd48
mrt 19 18:43:23 tuxedoos pipewire[8340]: pw.node: (bluez_input.00_04_32_8E_48_A2.0-107) running -> error (Received error event)
mrt 19 18:43:23 tuxedoos pipewire[8340]: pw.node: (bluez_output.00_04_32_8E_48_A2.1-100) suspended -> error (Received error event)
mrt 19 18:43:23 tuxedoos pipewire[8340]: pw.link: 0x61a0a9a7f830: one of the nodes is in error out:error in:suspended
mrt 19 18:43:23 tuxedoos pipewire[8340]: pw.link: 0x61a0a9c21350: one of the nodes is in error out:error in:suspended
```